# A fragment that hosts a SurfaceView only draws onto Canvas once

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-canvas, surfaceview

Good Evening,
 I minimized my large project onto a small scale one which still keeps all the aspects of issue I'm having. I'm using an activity that draws SurfaceView background underneath a single Button. On press that Button adds a new fragment (to an empty FrameLayout that's in MainActivities XML layout) which as well holds SurfaceView and three buttons in ConstraintLayout. Button works as intended and calls the Fragments, but only the static layout part is being drawn(three buttons) as for SurfaceView it only draws Initial Canvas and keeps redrawing same Frame, even tho Thread keeps on calling the Draw method with updated values(in this case Color). ThreadPool is used to create two instances that call update and draw methods for SurfaceView(MaintActivity and Fragment) class objects(this part works as intended).
I'm also getting this line in Log, right about where the issue begins.

```
    D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: >> INIT 
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: SURFACE CREATED
D/MY_FRAGMENT: SURFACE CREATED
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: SURFACE CHANGED
D/MY_FRAGMENT: SURFACE CHANGED
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: DRAW PLANET
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb2d1d780, tid 9982
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: DRAW PLANET
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: DRAW PLANET
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: DRAW PLANET
D/MY FRAGMENT VIEW: DRAW PLANET
```

Code samples bellow:

```
    package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private MyActivityView gameView;
    private static final String TAG = "MAIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gameView = findViewById(R.id.myview);
        SurfaceHolder gholder = gameView.getHolder();
        gholder.addCallback(this);
        gameView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button btn_map = findViewById(R.id.start);
        btn_map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        displayMapFragment();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">> SURFACE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">> SURFACE CHANGED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">> SURFACE DESTROYED");

    }

    private void displayMapFragment() {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myMapSpace, myFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        /*fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, simpleFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        mButton.setText(R.string.close);
        isFragmentDisplayed = true;*/
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.badcompany.testfragmentview.MyActivityView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myMapSpace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyActivityView.java

```
    package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyActivityView extends ParentGameView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "MY ACTIVITY VIEW";
    public MyActivityView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyActivityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public MyActivityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyActivityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CREATED");
        MyExecutor.getInstance().execute(new GameRunnable(surfaceHolder, this));
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CHANGED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE DESTROYED");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, 100, 200, paint);
    }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "MY_FRAGMENT";
    private  MyFragmentView myFragmentView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, viewGroup, false);
        myFragmentView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
        SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = myFragmentView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        myFragmentView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button selectGalaxyMap = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_galaxy_map);
        Button selectSolarSystemMap = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_solar_map);
        Button selectPlanetMap = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_planet_map);

        selectGalaxyMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SELECTED GALAXY");
                myFragmentView.setColor(1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECT GALAXY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        selectSolarSystemMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myFragmentView.setColor(2);
                Log.d(TAG, "SELECTED SYSTEM");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECT SYSTEM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        selectPlanetMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SELECT PLANET", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myFragmentView.setColor(3);
                Log.d(TAG, "SELECTED PLANET");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CHANGED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE DESTROYED");
    }
}
```

fragment_my.xml

```
    <com.badcompany.testfragmentview.MyFragmentView
        android:id="@+id/myMapView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_planet_map"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="SELECT PLANET"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_solar_map"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_select_planet_map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="SELET SYSTEM"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_galaxy_map"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_select_solar_map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="SELECT GALAXY"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyFragmentView extends ParentGameView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "MY FRAGMENT VIEW";
    private int Colors;

    public MyFragmentView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyFragmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyFragmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyFragmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        Log.d(TAG, ">> INIT ");
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        if(Colors == 2)
            drawSolarMap(canvas);
        else if(Colors == 1)
            drawGalaxyMap(canvas);
        else drawPlanetMap(canvas);
    }

    private void drawGalaxyMap(Canvas canvas){
        Log.d(TAG, "DRAW GALAXY");
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, 100, 100, paint);
    }

    private void drawSolarMap(Canvas canvas){
        Log.d(TAG, "DRAW SYSTEM");
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, 100, 100, paint);
    }

    private void drawPlanetMap(Canvas canvas){
        Log.d(TAG, "DRAW PLANET");
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, 100, 100, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        super.update();
    }

    public void setColor(int color){
        Colors = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CREATED");
        MyExecutor.getInstance().execute(new GameRunnable(surfaceHolder, this));
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CHANGED");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE DESTROYED");
    }
}
```

Extra classes that might not have relevance
GameInterface.java

```
package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

/**
 * Created by Donatas on 18/12/2018.
 */

import android.graphics.Canvas;
public interface GameInterface {
    public void draw(Canvas canvas);
    public void update();
}
```

ParentGameView.java

```
package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ParentGameView  extends SurfaceView implements GameInterface{
    private static final String TAG = "PARENT_GAME_VIEW";
    protected int x = 0;
    public ParentGameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ParentGameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ParentGameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ParentGameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }


    @Override
    public void update() {
        x++;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);

    }

}
```

MyExecutor.java

```
package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;
```

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyExecutor {
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

```
public static ExecutorService getInstance(){
    return executor;
}

public static void ShutDown(){
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

}

GameRunnable.java

```
package com.badcompany.testfragmentview;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "GAME_RUNNABLE";
    private  volatile boolean running = true;
    private  final int maxFPS = 30;
    private  double averageFPS;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private  volatile ParentGameView gameView;

    public GameRunnable(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, ParentGameView gameView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gameView = gameView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        long startTime;
        long timeMillis = 1000/maxFPS;
        long waitTime;
        int frameCount = 0;
        long totalTime = 0;
        long targetTime = 1000/maxFPS;
        while(running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                if(canvas != null){
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                        gameView.update();
                        gameView.draw(canvas);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Thread finished work");
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if(canvas != null){
                    try{
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
            timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime - timeMillis;
            try{
                if(waitTime>0)
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if(frameCount == maxFPS){
                averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
                frameCount = 0;
                totalTime = 0;
                //debug System.out.println("AVERAGE FPS: " + avaragFPS);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking into this and if you need additional info leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your post contains a lot of code, and I suspect a lot of it is not relevant to the actual problem you are experiencing. To help others that want to help you, and also future users with the same problem, please have a look at **[how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Found an awful solution myself, the issue is that MainActivity does not ask for next frame because it deems fragment view to be finished, calling `invalidate()` method in a Thread makes the activity to keep on asking for updated views.
If you manage to find a better solution please update this post, thanks.